# Set the default value of DesignerSerializationVisibility to hidden

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Is there a way to set the a default value for the attribute `DesignerSerializationVisibility` for all the properties of a given class?

In practice, a way to switch the default behavior of *black-listing* the properties with a *white-list* approach.

Thanks

Comment: What's the main problem which makes you to think about such solution?

Comment: I have lots of properties in a control class and I want to exclude most of them from the Designer without messing up the code with attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **My preferance**

You can provide default values for properties in constructor and decorate them using suitable [`DefaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute, then the designer will serialize them only if the value of them is different than default value.

Also if you need to make them invisible at design-time, you can simply decorate them using [`Browsable(false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) then they will not be shown at design time.

Also you can check [`DesignMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode(v=vs.110).aspx) in property setter to prevent setting a value for the property at design time and make it a run-time property.

I also answer your question which you need to *Not serialize properties that doesn't have DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute*.

> At least the approach will introduce a really useful feature to you
>   which you may find helpful in the future.

### **Not serialize properties that doesn't have DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute**

> A way to switch the default behavior of blacklisting the properties
>   with a white list approach.

As an option you can create a custom type descriptor for your component and using custom property descriptors which it returns, tell the designer to don't serialize properties that doesn't have [`DesignerSerializationVisibility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

This way when you want the designer serialize a property you should decorate it with `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute with `visible` as value.

**Implemetaion**

The designer ask the [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) of a property to decide to serialize the property. If the [`ShouldSerialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.shouldserializevalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the descriptor returns `true` it serializes the property, otherwise it doesn't serialize the property.

To change this behavior you should override that method. To make the designer to use your property descriptor, you should register a custom [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) for your class. The provider should provide a custom [`TypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) for your class. The custom type descriptor should return a list of your new `PropertyDescriptor` which you override that method.

**Important Note:** To test the implementations, you should restart the visual studio.

**TypeDescriptionProvider**

Here we create a custom type description provider for our component. Then we will register the provider for our component.

```
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
       : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(object))) { }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, 
                                                            object instance)
    {
       ICustomTypeDescriptor baseDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
       return new MyTypeDescriptor(baseDescriptor);
    }
}
```

**TypeDescriptor**

Here we implement our type descriptor which it's job is returning a list of our custom property descriptors.

```
public class MyTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    ICustomTypeDescriptor original;
    public MyTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor originalDescriptor)
        : base(originalDescriptor)
    {
        original = originalDescriptor;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { });
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = base.GetProperties(attributes).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                             .Select(p => new MyPropertyDescriptor(p))
                             .ToArray();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties);
    }
}
```

**PropertyDescriptor**

Here is the implementation of our custom property descriptor. The implementation of most properties and methods is trivial. Only for `ShouldSerialize` method, we decide based on having `DesignerSerializationVisibility`

```
public class MyPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    PropertyDescriptor original;
    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor originalProperty)
        : base(originalProperty)
    {
        original = originalProperty;
    }

    // Implement other properties and methods simply using return original
    // The implementation is trivial like this one:
    // public override Type ComponentType
    // {
    //     get { return original.ComponentType; }
    // }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        if (original.Attributes.OfType<DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute>()
                .Count() == 0)
            return false;

        return original.ShouldSerializeValue(component);
    }
}
```

**Component**

At last here is the component. As you see in the component code, we decorated a property (white list strategy) to be serialized. All other properties will not serialize because it's new behavior which we attached to our properties.

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class MyCustomClass : Component
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: Thanks, a really helpful response... :)

Comment: For learning purpose, you can also override `Attributes` property of `PropertyDescriptor` and check if the property doesn't have a `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute attached, then you add an instance of the attribute with value of `DesignerSerializationVisibility.None` to the attributes of property.

Answer (score 0):

To further extend @RezaAghaei's excellent answer, I replaced ShouldSerializeValue with the below (apols for vb.net):

```
 Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
    
    Dim c = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(component)
    For Each a In c
        If a.TypeId.Name = "NoSerializationPropsAttribute" Then
            Dim attr As NoSerializationPropsAttribute = a
            If attr.PropNames.Contains(Me.Name) Then
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return True

End Function
```

This lets me decorate the class with the props I want to mask out of deserialization, and therefore skip the need of decorating each property.

```
    <NoSerializationProps(PropNames:={"DisabledColor", "SelectedColor", "LostFocusColor"})>
```

One could easily flip it to a WhiteList instead.

```
Public Class NoSerializationPropsAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Overridable Property PropNames As String() = {}
End Class
```

Now if someone could point me to a way of overriding IsBrowsable in the PropertyDescriptor it would be awesome.