# Dynamically apply multiple instances of an Attribute to a Property using a list

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I define multiple attributes on a class:

```
[CustomAttribute("a", state = 0)]
[CustomAttribute("b", state = 0)]
...
[CustomAttribute("z", state = 0)]
public class MyClass { ... }
```

The values (`"a"`, `"b"`, on through to `"z"`) are also used elsewhere in the program, so right now, I have a duplicate array of names.

```
public static readonly string[] listOfNames = new [] { "a", "b", ..., "z" };
```

I can recover the names from the attributes using reflection to build `listOfNames`, but is there a way to do the reverse and define the attributes from `listOfNames`? I suspect not, but then is there a clearer way to at least avoid repeating the `CustomAttribute` bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zz5httw(v=vs.110).aspx) to add class-level attributes to a type at run-time:

```
string[] listOfNames = new [] { "a", "b", "c" };
var attributes = listOfNames.Select(x=>new CustomAttribute(x)).ToArray();
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(MyClass), attributes);
```

Also as another option you can create a [`CustomTypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) for your type. In the custom type descriptor, you return custom [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) objects for the properties of your type and in the property descriptor, you return a custom set of attributes for the property. The key point in property descriptor is overriding [`Attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.memberdescriptor.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Then create a [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and register it for your type to provide the custom type description.  This way you can use a single attribute instead of all those attributes.

To see an implementation  take a look at this post: [Combining Control Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503146/combining-control-attributes).

Comment: Probably the first option satisfied you, while maybe it's enough for now, but keep the second solution in mind, it may help you in future, the linked post is really useful for cases which frameworks use standard .NET type description mechanisms. For example Windows Forms or ASP.NET MVC use the mechanism.