# Too many attributes decorated - How can I simplify it?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization

My requirement is to create `common` class library to use between `EntityFramework` project and `JSON` serialization project.I ended up with below  class and properties which is decorated by `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Runtime.Serialization` attributes.

I feel, it's over burden. Can I use only `Newtonsoft.Json` attributes, so that I can remove all `System.Runtime.Serialization` attributes. If I do so, will my `code first entity framework` able to generate required schema in database?

```
[DataContract]
public partial class CompanyGroup:BaseEntity
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name", Required = Required.Always)]
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Also, I see `[JsonRequired]` attribute, how it is different from `[Required]`?

Is `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` is enough for EF?

Basically what is the best practice while writing the `common` class libraries?

Comment: `I feel, it's over burden.` Unless there is another way to achieve it with fewer attributes, it is not excessive.

Comment: Your class violates [SRP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and that will lead to this.

Comment: @SirRufo  Okay, but if i go by that route I will end up with duplicate classes and maintaining the code is hard. Basically I am getting json input and I am storing it in DB after serialization. "Id" will not come from "json" input, but DB shall have ID column which may be guid.

Comment: Well, I heard such arguments against SOLID too much. You should watch some Uncle Bob videos :o)

Comment: Usually you can omit explicitly providing the property name if it’s serialized name matches the properties name. Also you can comma-separate multiple attributes, so you could just write `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always), Required, DataMember]` to make it less verbose.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503146/combining-multiple-attributes-to-a-single-attribute