# How would I create a custom attribute that uses another?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, attributes

I have created a simple custom attribute called SerializedField

```
public class SerializedFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
   
}
```

I am also using Json and I want o be able to have this attribute automatically include [JsonProperty]. Is this possible?

Instead of this

```
[JsonProperty]
[SerializedField]
private int colliderType = 0;
```

I would like to simply have

```
[SerializedField]
private int colliderType = 0;
```

This way anything marked with [SerializedField] automatically gets serialized by Json.

Comment: You don't need anything like this. Just use standard [JsonProperty]  for a private field to get automatically  serialized by Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: You could create a [custom contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094764) that checks for the presence of the `[SerializedField]` attribute when applied to private fields and includes them in the serialization contract.  Does that answer your question?  Honestly I'm not sure it's worth it though because you will still need to apply `[JsonProperty]` to modify any of the 16 different [`JsonProperty` properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm)  such as the property name or the default value handling.

Comment: you can use JsonIgnore ... with conditions... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a single attribute that applies two different attributes simultaneously.<sup>[1]</sup>  Instead, you could create a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that automatically serializes private fields marked with `[SerializedField]`.  First, define the following resolver:

```
public class IncludeSerializedFieldsResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // TODO: Check the interaction of [SerializedField] with memberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn and MemberSerialization.Fields.
    // TODO: Decide whether fields marked with [SerializedField] and [JsonIgnore] should be serialized.  Currently they are not.
    // TODO: Decide the interaction between [SerializedField] and data contract attributes -- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member is FieldInfo f && !f.IsPublic 
            && Attribute.IsDefined(f, typeof(SerializedFieldAttribute)) 
            && !Attribute.IsDefined(f, typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute)))
        {
            property.Readable = property.Writable = true;
        }
        return property;
    }

    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var members = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
        var initialCount = members.Count;
        var toAdd = objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(f => Attribute.IsDefined(f, typeof(SerializedFieldAttribute)) 
                   && !Attribute.IsDefined(f, typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute)))
            .Where(f => members.IndexOf(f, 0, initialCount) < 0); // Don't add private members that already got added for some other reason, e.g. being marked with [JsonProperty]
        members.AddRange(toAdd);
        return members;
    }
}

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SerializedFieldAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Then serialize with the following settings:

```
// See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver
// For best performance you should cache and reuse this statically.
IContractResolver resolver = new IncludeSerializedFieldsResolver {  
    // Modify any properties as required, e.g.
    // NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = resolver,
    // Add other settings as required.
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootModel, settings);
```

Notes:

- Honestly I can't recommend doing this.  Using a single attribute like `[SerializedField]` to control multiple serializers would seem to violate the single responsibility principle, and might make your code harder to understand rather than easier.  Plus you will have to apply `[JsonProperty]` anyway to modify any of the 16 different [`JsonProperty` properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) such as the property name, so you will probably end up having to apply it pretty often in practice even with the custom resolver.
- The field will not be serialized if `[JsonIgnore]` is also applied.
- Newtonsoft [recommends](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver) you statically cache and reuse contract resolvers for best performance.
- You will get an exception trying to serialize a derived type with a serialized private field with the same name as a serialized private field in the base type.  If this happens you will have to use a different JSON property name for one of the two fields.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N2Qn9g).

---

<sup>[1]</sup>  I checked the following, and none will do what you need:

1. C# [does not support macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) so you can't make a macro that applies both attributes.
2. [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonPropertyAttribute.cs#L35) is currently sealed, so you cannot make `SerializedFieldAttribute` inherit from it.
3. The trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38504552) by [Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) to [Combining multiple Attributes to a single Attribute - Merge Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38503146/3744182) will not work because Json.NET uses use reflection instead of type description to gather metadata.