# Add attribute to all properties of a class and its descendants

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, system.componentmodel

I'm working with workflow foundation and I have a base [`CodeActivity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.codeactivity) that is super class of all my activities.

I'm adding [`Category`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute) as 'input' or 'output' to properties to ease the work of those using the activities. Example:

```
public class MyActivity : MyBaseActivity
{
    [Category("Input")]
    public InArgument<string> User { get; set; }

    [Category("Input")]
    public InArgument<int> Department { get; set; }

    [Category("Output")]
    public OutArgument<string> Supervisor { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

All my InArgument's will have category set as input, as well as OutArguments.

**There is a way of doing this without writting `[Category("Input")]` to every single property?**

I've tried by an inherited version of InArgument:

```
[Category("Input")]
public sealed class ActivityInput<T> : InArgument<T> { }
```

But `InArgument` is `sealed` so is not possible that way.

Comment: It should be possible using type descriptors. The question is old, but future readers may want to give it a try using something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36337249/3110834).

Comment: I stopped working with WWF months ago due to a project change, but will have this in mind should I go to another project like that. Thanks for the info @RezaAghaei =)