# ShouldSerializeXXX() Dynamic Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I'm making a form application with a 'propertygrid control.'
I want all properties to always display with non-bold text --- always treat all properties as a 'default' value. And this 'Test' class has a lot of properties.
I think the best way is to dynamically implement 'ShouldSerializeXXX' methods. Manually implementation is lacking in flexibility and not smart.
I know the way to dynamically implement a function using ’DynamicMethod class'　[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod?view=net-5.0]. But the 'ShouldSerializeXXX' function has an effect just by defining, I have no idea how to implement the function.
Can anybody tell me the way to do this? Sorry for my poor English.

```
public class Test
{
      public int AAA {get;set;}
      public string BBB {get;set;}
      public bool CCC {get;set;}
      ...
      ...

      //This class has a lot of property, so I want to dynamically implement the function like this:
      private bool ShouldSerializeAAA(){ return false; }
      private bool ShouldSerializeBBB(){ return false; }
      ...
}
```

Comment: You can achieve it using a custom type descriptor: Look at this example: [Set the default value of DesignerSerializationVisibility to hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36337249/3110834).

Comment: Or use a proxy like this: [Hide some properties in PropertyGrid at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618536/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically implementing a method *that needs to then be discovered by reflection* is not trivial, and would require dynamically creating a sub-type of `Test` and making sure that all your instances are actually of the sub-type - not an appealing proposition.

There are some more appealing options, though;

1. generate the extra methods - this *could* be a few lines of throw-away reflection code (and a unit test that checks that they all exist) that just spits out however-many versions of `public bool ShouldSerialize{Name}() => false;`
2. look into the type-descriptor/property-descriptor API; a custom type-description-provider can provide custom property-descriptors, and it is *they* that get to say whether something needs to be serialized or not; it is just that the *default* implementation looks for `ShouldSerialize{Name}()`

Honestly, option 1 seems by far the easiest option here - and it will involve less mess at runtime; you could get option 1 implemented in a few minutes, *including* the test to make sure you don't miss any new ones

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question: what is 'the extra properties'? Do you mean properties in which generate 'public bool ShouldSerialize{Name}() => false;' methods?

Comment: @J.Green I meant the extra methods instead; just auto-generate them, and write a test that checks that they all exist using reflection

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is using a custom type descriptor as it's already addressed in Marc's answer. You can see an implementation in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36337249/3110834). You can make the linked post working for you easily by changing override of ShouldSerializeValue and return false. That's all.

But here I'd like to share another option, a shorter answer, which needs less effort but basically do the same for you. Using a Proxy when passing objects to PropertyGrid:

Assuming you have a common class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

This is how you use the proxy:

```
var myOriginalObject = new MyClass();
this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new ObjectProxy(myOriginalObject);
```

And here is the result after changing properties:

[image]

This is the `ObjectProxy` which is a class derived from `CustomTypeDescriptor` will do the magic for you. And here's the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class ObjectProxy : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public object Original { get; private set; }
    public List<string> BrowsableProperties { get; private set; }
    public ObjectProxy(object o)
        : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(o).GetTypeDescriptor(o)) => Original = o;
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] a)
    {
        var props = base.GetProperties(a).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
            .Select(p => new MyPropertyDescriptor(p));
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props.ToArray());
    }
    public override object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd) => Original;
}
public class MyPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    PropertyDescriptor o;
    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor originalProperty)
        : base(originalProperty) => o = originalProperty;
    public override bool CanResetValue(object c) => o.CanResetValue(c);
    public override object GetValue(object c) => o.GetValue(c);
    public override void ResetValue(object c) => o.ResetValue(c);
    public override void SetValue(object c, object v) => o.SetValue(c, v);
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object c) => false;
    public override AttributeCollection Attributes => o.Attributes;
    public override Type ComponentType => o.ComponentType;
    public override bool IsReadOnly => o.IsReadOnly;
    public override Type PropertyType => o.PropertyType;
}
```