# BindingSource.BindingReset not working

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, bindingsource

I have the bound my `DataGridView` to `BindingSource` but when I call `ResetBinding()` the `DataGridView` doesn't get updated to show only those records which have WhenDeleted column value as null:

```
public partial class LabourSetup : DisplayControl
{
    private List<LABOUR> labourCollection = new List<LABOUR>();
    protected BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        labourCollection = Query.GetLabours();
        bs.DataSource = labourCollection;
        this.dataGridViewX1.DataSource = bs;
    }
    // This method doesn't actually delete Labour from table just mark the column with the present day date. So that it could not be shown in Grid View
    public void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["WhenDeleted"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        MainForm.GlobalCache.SaveChanges();
        labourCollection = Query.GetLabours();
        //bs.DataSource = labourCollection;  // works when I un comment this line
        bs.ResetBindings(false);  // doesnt work
        }
    }
}
```

In above, why do I have to write:

```
//bs.DataSource = labourCollection;  // works when I un comment this line. Why?
```

Since binding source is already bound to labourCollection in PopulateGrid() method. ResetBinding() should not show record marked for deletion(WhenDeleted not null).

```
public class Query
{
    internal static List<LABOUR> GetLabours()
    {
   // Getting only those records which are not marked for deletion
      return MainForm.GlobalCache.LABOURs.Local.Where(lab => lab.WhenDeleted == null).ToList();
    }
}
```

In above `GlobalCache` is `DbContext`.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why this code doesn't work?**

```
labourCollection = Query.GetLabours();
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Let's see the reason. 
There are 2 problem in above code:

1. `labourCollection = Query.GetLabours();` doesn't have any impact on `DataSource` of `bs`. It just assigns a new list to `labourCollection` variable. But previous list is still in memory. `labourCollection` just points to the new list, but `bs` uses the list which you assigned to its `DataSource` property. So the changed item is still there in the list which you used as `DataSource` of `bs`.
   Remember [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) concepts. If you assign a new object to a variable, the previous object is untouched. You just missed the pointer to that object and the variable points to the new object.
2. [`ResetBindings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx)   method just causes a control bound to the `BindingSource` to reread all the items in the list and refresh their displayed values. It doesn't reload data from database or somewhere else. It just look into `DataSource` and shows data in the bound control again. So the the value which you changed will be there in list and you can not expect the `ResetBindings` perform anything special for you.

**So why the this code works?**

```
labourCollection = Query.GetLabours();
bs.DataSource = labourCollection;
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

It works because of `bs.DataSource = labourCollection;`. The last line of code is useless. When you assign a new list to `DataSource` of `BindingSource` it cause refreshing bound controls and you don't need to call `ResetBindings`.

**What's the usage of ResetBindings?**

It's useful to refresh grid to show values from data source, when the data source doesn't support 2-way data-binding.

If you change a property of `LABOUR` in the list using `labourCollection[0].Property = "Value";` or even if you remove an item from the list using `labourCollection.RemoveAt(0);` the `DataGridView` will not show new value of the `Property` or even it's not aware of removed item.

If you call `bs.ResetBindings(false)` the `DataGridView` shows new value of property. Also doesn't show the removed item.

```
labourCollection[0].SomeProperty = "Some Value";
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: Thank you Reza for the detailed explanation. I tried Filter property of BindingSource to include only those records where WhenDeleted is null. But then it says my list (local in my case) should implement IBindingListView for desired result. Don't know how to achieve that without bs.DataSource = labourCollection; in btnDel_Click event

Comment: You're welcome. You can remove the item from `labourCollection` after you set the property value. Don't worry, it will not be removed from the context. It only will be removed from the `labourCollection`.

Comment: Also setting the data source again is not a big deal, what's the problem with  this?

Comment: Take a look at this post: [How to filter data from Entity Data Source in Windoes form application using C# that can be editable using gridview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977042/how-to-filter-data-from-entity-data-source-in-windoes-form-application-using-c-s) you may find it useful.

Comment: The linked post is useful in general and good to read. But in this case, since you don't want to remove the item from context, you need to just remove the item from `labourCollection`. Also `labourCollection` **should not be** `db.Labours.Local.ToBindingList();`

Comment: Yes you are correct bro. Setting DataSource to new list every time when a record is deleted makes no point in using BindingSource then. Now I'm removing it from labourCollection as you suggested. That at least seems elegant from the available suggestions.