# DataGridView : Update SQL Database when cell value changed

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a form which contains DataGridView and have created first column as checkbox column and fullrowselect is True.
I want like when I click the checkbox of the row or change the checkbox value of the selected row, that particular record should be updated in the database...

I wrote the query properly but facing some problems mentioned below.

Now I first tried in cell click event...

```
 Private Sub DGVHelp_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVHelp.CellClick
    Try
        If PubHelpCode = "ACTMAST" And e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then 'if only checkbox column is clicked
            cmd = New SqlCommand("Update FAMPAR SET Tag = '" & DGVHelp(0, e.RowIndex).Value & "' where Account_Code = '" & DGVHelp(1, e.RowIndex).Value & "' ", con1)
            ExecuteQuery(con1, "EDITCHECKBOX") ' Its my UDF
            DGV_Reset()' This clears the datagrid and fetch the data again
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I click the checkbox cell (First column), the event first runs and then the value of the cell is changed... i.e during cellclick event, the DGVHelp(0, e.RowIndex).Value doesn't change its value if its ticked or unticked.

I even tried cellvaluechanged event but it hanged the program by some continuous process that I don't know...

Which event should I use to complete my task??

If any other opinion/idea relating to this task is there then please share...

The Code OneDrive link shared below..
[Solution Code link](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlEp4GyzKDzFiL8zTA6pwIV_2my9Eg)

Comment: When you click on a `DataGridViewCheckBox`, the changes which you make on the cell doesn't commit immediately to the data source until you finish editing the cell, then changes will be pushed to data source. The `CellClick` or `CellContentClick` will be OK, but you need to commit changes to data source, otherwise the value which you read is not the value which you see. Take a look at this post:[DataGridView CheckBox column doesn't apply changes to the underlying bound object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40348082/3110834)

Comment: Don't look for any other events, just use `CellClick` or `CellContentClick` [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34090635/3110834).

Comment: Ya I try @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event.  This is the best event to work with in your case. It is not a good idea to use `MouseClick` event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Inside the event sub use the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` property `e.columnIndex` to check that the colunn edited is the one containing the checkbox. Otherwise you have to check your code.

> it is better to use a `Using` clause when working with sqlcommand class

```
Using cmd as New SqlCommand("Update FAMPAR SET Tag = '" & DGVHelp(0, e.RowIndex).Value & "' where Account_Code = '" & DGVHelp(1, e.RowIndex).Value & "' ", con1)

        ExecuteQuery(con1, "EDITCHECKBOX") ' Its my UDF

End Using
```

**EDIT 1:**

After checking you solution. it is not so clear but you can do some workaround.

1- Define a boolean variable `m_BoolValueChanged`

```
Private m_BoolValueChanged as Boolean = True
```

2- Use this variable in `DGVHelp_CellValueChanged` Sub to prevent infinite loop. like to following:

```
Private Sub DGVHelp_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVHelp.CellValueChanged
    Try
        If PubHelpCode = "ACTMAST" And e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then

            If m_BoolValueChanged Then

            m_BoolValueChanged = False


            cmd = New SqlCommand("Update FAMPAR SET Tag = '" & DGVHelp(0, e.RowIndex).Value & "' where Account_Code = '" & DGVHelp(1, e.RowIndex).Value & "' ", con1)
            ExecuteQuery(con1, "EDITCHECKBOX")
            Dim ri As Integer = DGVHelp.CurrentRow.Index
            DGV_Reset()
            DGVHelp.Rows(ri).Selected = True

            m_BoolValueChanged = False


            End If


        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

You may find better solution but this will helps

Comment: I said I tried cell value changed... I'll see and tell where it is stuck in loop which hangs the software.

Comment: If it is changing cell value then it will enter infinite loop

Comment: Also fetching data may cause unfinite loop

Comment: I got the loop but I can't show it here... Can I get your Email, the code is quite big to post here and it might get off topic... Or email me

Comment: You can attach your solution to cloud and provide the link. So everyone can help

Comment: Oh ya, thats a better option, wait I do..!

Comment: Edited my answer so check it up. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

In this problem better solution will be use `DataGridView.CellMouseClick` event. This event will fire when you only click on any cell.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender as Object, e as DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) _ 
    Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick

    'todo

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I thought of mouseclick event but if the checkbox changed with a spacebar then it won't work...@mww