# Attribute not registering on partial Entity class/interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csvhelper

I am using the [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) framework to push data into Salesforce via the Salesforce Bulk API. The application is a simple C# Console app using Entity Framework. I'm currently working with the `Account` object only but will be adding other tables/objects so I want to make the code as reusable as possible.

One of my challenges is there are fields in the source table that I need to ignore using the CSVHelper [Ignore] attribute. This `Key` field is ignored so long as I directly place the attribute on the auto-generated Entity class property like so:

```
public partial class Account
{
    [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Ignore]
    public long Key { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

But, this is not preferred since this file be regenerated when I add other tables/objects to the program via the Entity Designer.

So the first solution I tried was to simply create another partial class with a different file name but same class signature and property:

```
public partial class Account
{
  [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Ignore]
  public long Key { get; set; }
}
```

However, this would not compile since [you cannot use the same property in separate partial file to define a property attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480940/is-it-possible-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-property-in-a-partial-class):

[image]

So I did some research and I found several options to avoid placing the attribute directly on the auto-generated Entity code.

Method 1:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Account.MetaData))]
public partial class Account
{
    internal class MetaData
    {
        [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Ignore]
        long Key { get; set; }
    }
}
```

While this compiles, the `[Internal]` attribute does not register and code does not ignore the `Key` field.

Method 2:

```
public interface IEntityMetadata
{
    [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Ignore]
    long Key { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IEntityMetadata))]
public partial class Account : IEntityMetadata
{
}
```

Again, the code compiles, but the `[Internal]` attribute does not register and code does not ignore the `Key` field.

Method 3:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AccountAttributes))]
public partial class Account
{ }

public class AccountAttributes
{
    [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Ignore]
    public long Key { get; set; }
}
```

Just like the previous two methods, the code compiles, but the `[Internal]` attribute does not register and code does not ignore the `Key` field.

Only when the `[Ignore]` attribute is applied directly to the auto-generated Entity `Account` class property will the code ignore the `Key` field.

My research suggests that any of the 3 methods I used should have accomplished my goal. What might I be missing that is preventing these methods from working?

Thank you.